# Adress of Variables passed as call by Value

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I was just playing with the functions and parameters.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int function(char *str,int b);
int main()
{
       char *str = new char[10];
       memset(str,0,10);

       int a = 10;
       int b = 10;
       function(str,b);
       function(str,a);
}

//FUnction Definition
 int function(char *str,int b)
 {
      cout << &str << "\t" << &b << "endl"

      return 0;
 }
```

I am compiling this code in VS2010 C++ ,, 
When we pass something by value , a new value is created copying the contents from the variable which is passed. So definitely `b` at the function body will be having different address. 
What i am seeing is that the function parameters remains at the same address location in multiple calls.

What i am guessing is that parameters of the Functions are each mapped with memory locations, which wil contain the variables called on Function

I just want to know is this so or there is something else.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218/509868

Answer (score 0):

The addresses of local variables can be re-used for subsequent calls. Nothing wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the local variables are at the same address in memory is because you are calling from `main -> function` and the stack is always being adjusted in the same way to make the locals for `function`

If you changed your code to that `main` called another function which then called `function` then you'd notice that the local variables and parameter have a different address as they'll be in a stack frame at a different address.

NOTE: All this is assuming your compiler isn't doing and optimizations.